# How to read a file content from Bitbucket via a Mulejob?

Tags: bitbucket-server, mulesoft

I have a requirement to integrate data from Bitbucket through Mulejob. Not looking for CI/CD integration, I mean actually read content of a repository file through Mule. Also given, I am a newbie to Mule.

I am able to read a content of a repo branch through Mule using Atlassian Stash connector.

**Q1**: Does this flow actually retrieve file or just metadata of files? Able to print names of files.

**Q2**: Assuming files are indeed retrieved, how do I read the contents of the file? Tried using Mule Requester to read output payload of Stash connector, but I see that a payload is null when I print it. No errors are thrown, just blank payload. Appreciate your help!

My Mule flow: *http -> Stash Connecter (read files) -> For Each -> Mule Requester: Retrieve File -> Log payload*.

Mule to Stash connector API I am using: http://hotovo.github.io/mule-stash-connector/mule/stash-config.html#commit-files-get

Syntax I am trying with Mule Requester instance: `file://#[payload.value]`

Output:

> INFO  2019-08-09 14:37:07,691
>   [[test-bitbucket-connect].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01]
>   org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: FOR payload ---- Key:
>   repository/.java Value: repository/.java INFO 
>   2019-08-09 14:37:07,692
>   [[test-bitbucket-connect].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01]
>   org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising:
>   'file-connector-config.requester.1217682634'. Object is:
>   FileMessageRequester INFO  2019-08-09 14:37:07,692
>   [[test-bitbucket-connect].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01]
>   org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting:
>   'file-connector-config.requester.1217682634'. Object is:
>   FileMessageRequester INFO  2019-08-09 14:37:07,693
>   [[test-bitbucket-connect].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01]
>   org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Post retrieve File:
>   null

Comment: What is the payload inside the foreach? The connector documentation is not clear about that. You are trying to read the files from the filesystem. Does the connector write the files into the filesystem? Or is it just giving you a way to access it, like a stream?

Comment: Yes exactly, documentation is not helping. The payload I see is List<Map> and the map has key of file name and value as object (which i am assuming is the file?) but I am not sure. This is the first time I am using connector too, so not sure of how to use it.

Comment: try reading that value. If I have to make a guess I assume is an inputstream with the contents of the file.